# jquery next/prev button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a jquery questionnaire, when the user clicks on the next and prev buttons it will navigate to the next question [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/y725p/4/) i have noticed that my next and prev function does not next to the next question.

once the next button is click it mean't to go to the question and vise versa for the previous button. Below is a snippet of my code

```
if (parentContainer.next('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer').length) {
                parentContainer.hide();
                parentContainer.next('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer').show();
            }
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this issue

Comment: Your `for="option4` is wrong, If you change it to for="option1" to option4, then it works when you click the radio buttons. But then you don't need the next button. PS. You should also use `.on('click', function(){})`

Comment: You haven't posted any code that relates to the `click` event of your `next` and `previous` spans.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your selector was wrong..

try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/y725p/7/

```
$('.nodetest__nextBtn').click(function () {
    $('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer:visible').hide().next('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer').show();
});
    $('.nodetest__prevBtn').click(function () {
    $('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer:visible').hide().prev('.responsible-gaming__parentContainer').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the on() click function of jquery

`$( ".class" ).on( "click", function() {
  //do some stuff here;
});`

Comment: That will not solve the issue as the problem lies within the `for` property of the label / input